# How to list of all pie menus?

Tags: interface, pie-menu

Is there any resource (inside Blender, or in the manual etc.) that lists all the available pie menus?

Individual pie menus (e.g., those reached with backtick or shift-S) are mentioned in their relevant sections of the manual, but for a novice user it's hard to discover which settings are accessible through pie menus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in *Edit > Preferences > Addons*.

Search for the *Pie Menus* addon, and inside the description you can find the list of all the menus brought by this addons, their shortcuts, as well as checkboxes to disable the ones you don't like.

For all the other Pie menus in Blender, you can go in *Edit > Preferences > Keymap* and search for "*Pie*". It will show every key binding for every existing pie menus in every editor and interaction modes.

Comment: That addon appears to provide *additional* pie menus, but it doesn't serve as a list of the pie menus already available in Blender -- e.g., the backtick and shift-S menus I mentioned aren't in the list.

Comment: fixed, see the answer.